# How to Push Down Data Filters to Lowest Level while Consuming Snowflake View in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I am Consuming Snowflake View in Power BI Dashboard ; I noticed that Power BI reporting tool design is to run the Snowflake view (Direct Query Method)and consume all the data coming out of Snowflake View and then do the further filtering, transforming on the data in its own memory place. This has performance repercussions.
My Question is how do i bring  Power BI User Selected Parameters filtered data from Snowflake View into PowerBI ; as far as i know  Snowflake View doesn't have Parameterized View. Can i consume Snowflake UDTF (User Defined Table Function )in Power BI, i understand that Snowflake UDTF object can be Parameterized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QueryFolding (predicate push-down) in PowerBI. This will push the transformation to the source.
You will have to check the PowerBI documentation to see how this is done properly.

It should speed up all queries.